# Why do these values repeat when outputted from my .ajax() request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have no idea what's going on with my snippet of code. I'm trying to output values from a json request using .ajax().

This line of code:

```
$.each(posts, function(k, v){
    $("section ul").append("<li><p>" + v.webTitle + "</p></li>");   
});
```

Outputs the title of each post in a p tag on one line. So I added this to pull the thumbnail url too

```
$("section ul li").append("<p>" + v.fields.thumbnail + "</p>");
```

However, this line outputs this

[JSON preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12oWB.png)

Could someone tell me:

- Why this is happening with the images but not the text
- How i can amend my code to output one image per list item

Comment: ... 
because `$("section ul li")` selects more than one li...

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for that. So i should amend to select each individual lil in question?

Comment: you should select the one you want to insert the paragraph tag into. It's always the last one, right? better though would be to just add it to the htmlstring of the first line.

Comment: AHHhh! Done and done. thanks for that - no idea it would be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
$.each(posts, function(k, v){
    var li = $("<li>"); // create single li element
    li.append("<p>" + v.webTitle + "</p><p>" + v.fields.thumbnail + "</p>"); // append to it before we lose reference to it
    $("section ul").append(li); // append it only once to the ul
});
```

The main idea is to append more content to the `<li>` before you lose reference to it. What jQuery does in your code is create a li, append it to the ul, and forget about it, it doesn't keep a reference to it. And in the next line you were finding again `<li>` elements, but you received all of them, not the last one.